# Struct initialisation list is zero-ed instead of initialised to values

Tags: c++, optimization, linker, arm, embedded

I'd say I'm decent in C++, however I'm very new to linker scripts and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.
First off all, this is my linker script:

```
ENTRY(ISR_Reset)
MEMORY {
   FLASH   (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x80000,     LENGTH = 128K
   RAM     (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000   LENGTH = 36K
}
SECTIONS {
   .text : {
      *(.vector_table)
      *(.text.startup)
      *(.text)
      *(.rodata)
   } > FLASH

   __data_flash_source__ = ALIGN(4);
   .data : AT(__data_flash_source__) {
       __data_section_start__ = .;
       *(.data)
       *(.init_array)
       __data_section_end__ = .;
       __ram_end__ = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
   } > RAM

   .bss : {
       *(.bss)
   } > RAM
}
```

I copy the data from FLASH to RAM between `__data_section_start__` and `__data_section_end__`, then I zero out the rest of the RAM.
I'm using the following command to compile my code:
`arm-none-eabi-g++.exe .\src\start.s .\src\main.cpp -o .\bin\main -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -nostartfiles -T .\src\sam3u2e.ld -mthumb -pedantic -Wall -std=c++17 -ggdb -Ofast`

If I remove the `-Ofast` flag, and don't use any optimisation I get the following linker error:
`section .text._ZN4_PMCC2Ev LMA [0008019c,000801bf] overlaps section .data LMA [0008019c,0008019f]`
However if I do include it it compiles just fine, but when I try to initialise structs like so:

```
struct Example {
   unsigned int const ID;
   unsigned int volatile & some_register;
   Example(unsigned int const id, unsigned int const register_address) : ID(id),
                                                                         some_register(*((unsigned int volatile *)register_address)) {}
} instance(0x12345678, 0xDEADBEEF);
```

I notice in the disassembly that the address of `instance.some_register` is stored in FLASH, right after the `main()` function, but it doesn't seem to get referenced by any code even when writing to it like so:

```
instance.some_register = 1234;
```

The `instance.ID`, however, is being loaded from RAM, but from a higher address than the size of `.data`, which means it never gets copied from FLASH to RAM. But if I change the location of `.bss` from `> RAM` to `> FLASH` it tries to load the `instance.ID` from FLASH, which I don't understand, because the ID should be in `.rodata` anyway.

Furthermore I notice that even if I don't reference the struct at all in the code other than defining it that the address is still located in FLASH, I wonder if it'd be possible to tell the linker to not include code for initialised structs that aren't referenced anywhere?

**EDIT:** Linker sections:

[image: linker sections]

as you can see the .data section (that gets copied into RAM) is only 4 bytes in size.
However the assembly tries to load `instance.ID` and the address of `instance.some_register` from RAM ---that's higher than 0x20000004, which confuses me, because those values should be read-only anyways and therefore stored in flash?

**EDIT 2: I probably wasn't clear enough in what I want the code to do. I'll try explaining again.** I want to define a set of different structs, each of them would have different variables. Each variable references a device register (by setting the pointer of the variable to the address of the corresponding register). So when the user would write to those registers, for example: `peripheral.some_register = 123;` the value would be written to the actual physical register.

In the compiled (optimised) code I don't really want these structs to exist, so the CPU wouldn't need to deal with initialising data, and would instead just see it as a collection of pointers to different peripheral registers. Since it would be read-only data it could also be located in FLASH and so wouldn't need to use up any RAM.

I'm guessing that means I mustn't use constructors, as that would then mean the CPU will need to initialise them, even though the data is, again, read-only.
The user also won't need to create his own instances of the structs, in case that helps with anything.

I initally wanted to use constructors because there are some peripherals with over 50 registers each, that have the same offsets per peripheral, but different base addresses, so I was hoping to save myself some work by not needing to copy paste the same address for each register and add a number to it.

Comment: C++ requires more support than c.  You have static constructors.  Ini/fini and ctor/dtor might be good search terms.  You might also like ´c++filt´.

Comment: why dont you wrap bss with start and end/size and initialize bss cleanly instead of blindly running through ram?  Or at least zero first then init .data.

Comment: please show disassembly of relevant parts of the binary.

Comment: @old_timer I loop through through .data which is stored in FLASH to load it into RAM, and from the last address on to the end of ram I fill with zeroes. Why wouldn't that be 'clean'? Which disassembly would you like to see? The loading into RAM or compiled C++ code?

Comment: @artlessnoise I added those sections into the linker file, and now it compiles even without `-Ofast` and I see the constructors and destructors in the output file, however the program never calls those. To clarify I simply added `.init : { *(.init) } > FLASH` for .init, .fini, .ctor, and .dtor after the .text section. Also, wouldn't it be possible to store the register addresses in .rodata and have the assembly reference it whenever the user writes to a register? instead of having to deal with constructors/destructors?

Comment: @enzeys, because you are asking this question....why bother with initializing memory, if so then init first, pre stack, pre .data, etc.  If you have a .bss problem then as done with .data marry the linker and bootstrap and init only .bss

Comment: when you initialized sram with something other than zeros what did you see?  did the results change?

Comment: Those are treated as arrays of function pointers that _start calls before running main().

Comment: what does disassembly and readelf show?

Comment: @old_timer I tried clearing it to 0x41, and the struct values are now all 0x41. That's because the constructors never get called. The problem is that I want the struct values to be in .rodata anyway and stored in FLASH, but for some reason the linker wants them to be in RAM, even when they can't be modified.

Comment: @artlessnoise I'm also writing the startup assembly. I see that the compiler created the function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int), but how do I go ahead of calling it from _start? I mean what are the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things going on here. Let me try to tackle them with my also limited knowledge of linker scripts.

1. The error you see related to the symbol `.text._ZN4_PMCC2Ev` is typically due to an issue of lacking entries in the linker script. In this case you don't have a place for .text.*, so I would suggest you try to add `*(.text.*)`
2. I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't seem to get referenced", but `instance.some_register` would not be a symbol. Usually it would be loaded as an offset from the program counter. However, this will depend on how `instance` is allocated.
3. Maybe I'm missing something, but while `instance.ID` is constant, `instance` isn't. I would thus not expect that to be located in `.rodata`.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with linker syntax, what's the difference between *(.text) and *(.text.\*)?

Comment: `*(.text)` copies only a symbol named `.text` into that section. `*(.text.*)` would copy anything starting with `.text`. Come to think of it, you might actually get away with replacing `*(.text)` with `*(.text*)`.

Comment: That made it able to get compiled without the `-Ofast` option and without adding the .init .fini, .ctor, and .dtor sections, but the data is still all zero.